# How do I install lights in the ceiling with only red/black wire pairs?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to install some lights on my apartment ceiling, and took off the conduit box panel expecting to see hot neutral and Ground wires. Instead I found these six wires. Black and red only without any AC voltage reading near 120. The largest I got was 16 between a red and black pair. There is a black electrical tape round around two of the pairs and the other is unmarked.

What should I do to be able to hook up an AC Light fixture? Is it possible that any of these are a neutral or all all of these hot? Or are some of the red and black switches and the unmarked ones neutral?

I have tried so many different wire combinations with the multimeter with no promising AC readings.

What should I do?

[image: three jacketed cables with two conductors each]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136977/discussion-on-question-by-electrical-engineering-failure-how-do-i-install-lights).

Answer (score 4):

Red cables with red and black insulated conductors are usually fire alarm or smoke detectors!!!

That you measure 16v is further proof that this may be fire alarm or smoke heads!

The peak voltage is normally 24v but depending on the distance it may well look like 16 or Less.

I have seen some security systems with this wiring but
NEVER power or mains wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Based on 120V and the blue plastic box, it is a pretty safe bet this is US or Canada. Which means neutral **must** be white or gray. Which means this is either totally not to code or it is fire alarm or other wiring not meant for regular lighting circuits. **FULL STOP.**

In addition, if *apartment* means *rental* as it typically means in the US (not 100%,condos can be apartments too) then you can't do your own wiring anyway. And the possibility that you may have disabled half your floor's smoke alarms is one reason why...

Plus a rectangle blue box is not what you normally see for mounting ceiling lights, but perfectly fine as a fire alarm junction box.

Plus the wires were together for a reason. The only measurement (had they been a group of black and a group of white) would have been between the two groups.

**PUT IT ALL BACK TOGETHER THE WAY YOU FOUND IT**, and then look for another possible switched location. Which may not be in the ceiling - it may be a single receptacle on the wall.